# Global void*, making it pointer to structure pointer

Tags: pointers, void

I've something like:

```
struct list{
   struct list **next, **prev;
}
```

Global declaration:

```
struct list *threads = &((struct list){&threads, &threads});
void* vp_threads;      /Error here:  previous declaration of 'vp_threads' was here
vp_threads = threads;  //Error here: conflicting types for vp_threads
```

2nd way I tried:

```
void* vp_threads = threads; //Error: initializer element is not constant
```

I have to do this because ... (see below!)

```
void some_func()
{
   add_head(vp_threads, ...)
...
}

void add_head(void* x, ...)
{ ... }
```

(PS: And there's not main() or initialization function, this's core.c file kind of, implementing all the functions which are in .h)

Why this's not working, I'm just trying to make void* to point to my structure. what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing

```
vp_threads = threads;
```

in main ( or an initialization function )

you can't put a statement in global scope. your statement `vp_threads = threads;`  would have to live inside a function somewhere

Comment: I tried that, it gives me error "initializer element is not constant"

Comment: well this's core.c file, just implementation of functions. No main or any initialization function, that's why I want global.
I should have told in the question

Comment: have a function called core_init()   and call it

Comment: can't do so ... this's used by other functions in the same file .. !

Comment: that's ok,  once its initialized everything can use it